# Makefile for Linux and Mac with address sanitizer

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, clang

I am trying to write a makefile that I can use on linux and mac that builds with an address sanitizer. This works on my vagrant instance:

```
CC         = gcc
ASAN_FLAGS = -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-format-security
ASAN_LIBS  = -static-libasan
CFLAGS    := -Wall -Werror --std=gnu99 -g3
LDFLAGS   += -lpthread

all: hello

hello: tiny_queue.o hello.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(ASAN_FLAGS) $(CURL_CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(CURL_LIBS) $(ASAN_LIBS)
```

This works on `ubuntu/trusty64` but fails on my mac with

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Werror --std=gnu99 -g3 -I/opt/X11/include  -c -o hello.o hello.c
gcc -o hello -Wall -Werror --std=gnu99 -g3 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-format-security  tiny_queue.o hello.o -lpthread  -static-libasan
clang: error: unknown argument: '-static-libasan'
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how to write a compatible makefile for the mac and linux?

p.s. I'm very new to C, sorry if this question is super basic.

Comment: Build multi-threaded code with `-pthread` flag for both compiler and linker. `-lpthread` is not adequate.

Comment: please see [AddressSanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html)

Comment: That's not related to the C language. (Strictly speaking not even a makefile question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> CC         = gcc
> ASAN_FLAGS = -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wno-format-security
> ASAN_LIBS  = -static-libasan
> CFLAGS    := -Wall -Werror --std=gnu99 -g3
> LDFLAGS   += -lpthread
>
> all: hello
>
> hello: tiny_queue.o hello.o
>     $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(ASAN_FLAGS) $(CURL_CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(CURL_LIBS) $(ASAN_LIBS)
> ```

You should *not* specify an Asan library (or a UBsan library, for that matter). Since you are using the compiler driver to drive link, just use `-fsanitize=address` (this is the recommended way of doing it). Do *not* add `-static-libasan`. The compiler driver will add the proper libraries for you.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I removed the `ASAN_LIBS` section since the `-fsanatize=address` was already in the `ASAN_FLAGS`.